# script/generate on Windows: 'script' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, scripting

Whenever I try to use the Rails `script/generate` or `script/install` command I get this kind of error:

```
C:\workspace>script/generate bigcommand
'script' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

on windows, you probably need to invoke it like this: "ruby script\generate ..."

Answer (score 1):

instead of using "script/generate" I used "generate" and it stopped giving me errors