# Issue with Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using Delayed job for schedule work. As per doc I ran the following command for generating the migration file and model class for Delayed job.

`rails generate delayed_job:active_record`

but while running this command it is creating new rails project with generate as project name instead of generating the migration file and model class.
I ran this command from my rails root directory only.

I am unable to find the problem with this.
Could you please help us on this ?

I am getting the following output while running this command.

```
D:\Sravan\RailsProject>rails generate migration delayed_job:active_record
      exists
      exists  app/controllers
      exists  app/helpers
      exists  app/models
      exists  app/views/layouts
      exists  config/environments
      exists  config/initializers
      exists  config/locales
      exists  db
      exists  doc
      exists  lib
      exists  lib/tasks
      exists  log
      exists  public/images
      exists  public/javascripts
      exists  public/stylesheets
      exists  script/performance
      exists  test/fixtures
      exists  test/functional
      exists  test/integration
      exists  test/performance
      exists  test/unit
      exists  vendor
      exists  vendor/plugins
      exists  tmp/sessions
      exists  tmp/sockets
      exists  tmp/cache
      exists  tmp/pids
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  README
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  db/seeds.rb
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
   identical  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip  config/initializers/session_store.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
   identical  config/boot.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
   identical  script/about
   identical  script/console
   identical  script/dbconsole
   identical  script/destroy
   identical  script/generate
   identical  script/runner
   identical  script/server
   identical  script/plugin
   identical  script/performance/benchmarker
   identical  script/performance/profiler
   identical  test/test_helper.rb
   identical  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
   identical  public/404.html
   identical  public/422.html
   identical  public/500.html
   identical  public/index.html
   identical  public/favicon.ico
   identical  public/robots.txt
   identical  public/images/rails.png
   identical  public/javascripts/prototype.js
   identical  public/javascripts/effects.js
   identical  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
   identical  public/javascripts/controls.js
   identical  public/javascripts/application.js
   identical  doc/README_FOR_APP
   identical  log/server.log
   identical  log/production.log
   identical  log/development.log
   identical  log/test.log
```

Thanks,
Sravan A

Comment: Did you make sure to add `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` to yoru Gemfile?

Comment: I added gem "delayed_job" in gem file

Comment: Try `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` instead of just `delayed_job`

Comment: I have tried with 'delayed_job_active_record' gem.
Now we are getting the following error while running the bundle install

D:\Sravan\MyProject>bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
ArgumentError: undefined class/module YAML::Syck::DefaultKey
                   load at org/jruby/RubyMarshal.java:148
                  _load at c:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:289
                   load at org/jruby/RubyMarshal.java:148
             fetch_spec at c:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:119

Comment: I am using rails 2.3.5 version

Comment: you are using documentation for rails 3+ for delayed job - my guess is it would be something like `script/generate migration delayed_job` for rails 2

Comment: off topic: you should upgrade to 2.3.18 - there was major security issues found in older versions see http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/11/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-12-3-1-11-and-2-3-17-have-been-released/ AND 
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/3/18/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-13-3-1-12-and-2-3-18-have-been-released/

Comment: I have tried with rails script/generate migration delayed_job
this time we are getting the following o/p

      exists
      create  app/controllers
File exists - D:\Idea\8263_branch\script\generate

Comment: If possible could you please let me know how can we find model class and migration file for delayed_job
I will directly copy those two files instead of running this command

Answer (score 2):

please check the link
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v2.0

here you find the steps to integrate delayed_job for rails 2.x application.

Comment: As per doc I ran script/generate delayed_job.
but while running this we are getting 'script' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
So I tried with rails script/generate delayed_job

but this time we are getting the following o/p
      exists
      create  app/controllers
File exists - D:\Sravan\RailsProject\script\generate

Comment: If possible could you please let me know how can we find model class and migration file for delayed_job
I will directly copy those two files instead of running this command

Comment: I guess you are on windows. So instead of script/generate use 'ruby script\generate'. I got this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489274/script-generate-on-windows-script-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-externa#answer-1489291

Comment: I ran ruby script/generate delayed_job
Now we are getting the following error
Missing the Rails 2.3.5 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.5 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.

rails 2.3.5 gem is already available.

Comment: ohho.. okay.. look the delayed_job generator generates a migration file and "script/delayed_job" file. You can get those file content from https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/v2.0/generators/delayed_job/templates/migration.rb and https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/v2.0/generators/delayed_job/templates/script respectively . Try putting those files in your application directly.

Comment: while running db:migrate we are getting the following error
D:\Sravan\RailsProject>bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem binaries with `bundle install`
I have already ran bundle install

Comment: Sorry Sravan, I don't have much information about it :(. When I will get some info regarding this, will update you.